# What does ranked two places below mean?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, meaning-in-context, synonyms

If a statement says "India is ranked two places below China" What place does India hold if China is ranked 1? Is it rank 3 or 4?

Also, is there any difference between the following two sentences?

> India is ranked *below* China.
>
> India is ranked *behind* China.

Comment: India is ranked 3rd, that is below or behind China.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to decode such statements is to play with the numbers. What could it mean if India was ranked *one* place below China?

China is ranked "1".

0 places below (equal ranking) is "1"
1 place below is therefore "2"
2 places below is therefore "3"

Phrases like "n places below" are mostly interpreted as a distance rather than as a count of intervening positions.